# WMI query to check status task scheduler remotely

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, wmi, scheduler, wmi-query

I need WMI query to check status task scheduler remotely. Is there any way to do it ?

Actually we want to monitor server's task scheduler statuses remotely.

Comment: You are referring to `Windows Server Task Scheduler` ? What has that got to do with `SQL Server` ?

Comment: I am looking for wmiQuery specifically. Yes, Windows Server Task Scheduler.